# XSL How to select multiple values from one distinct value

Tags: xml, xslt, select, distinct-values

I wanted to extract the unique values with a function like select distinct.
Eventually I ended up using the xsl:key combination with for-each. I've managed to get the unique value of model, but I can't extract the style that belongs to that model.

I've tried to put together a sample XML.

```
    <PLAYER>
     <ALBUM>
      <MODEL>AA</MODEL>
      <STYLE>BB</STYLE>
      <NUMBER>1</NUMBER>
     </ALBUM>
     <ALBUM>
      <MODEL>FF</MODEL>
      <STYLE>GG</STYLE>
      <NUMBER>2</NUMBER>
     </ALBUM>
     <ALBUM>
      <MODEL>AA</MODEL>
      <STYLE>BB</STYLE>
      <NUMBER>3</NUMBER>
     </ALBUM>
     <ALBUM>
      <MODEL>FF</MODEL>
      <STYLE>GG</STYLE>
      <NUMBER>4</NUMBER>
     </ALBUM>
     <ALBUM>
      <MODEL>HH</MODEL>
      <STYLE>JJ</STYLE>
      <NUMBER>5</NUMBER>
     </ALBUM>
    </PLAYER>
```

I need to extract the unique value of MODEL with it's matching STYLE.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL Transform">
      <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:key name="model" match="/player/album/model/text()" use="." />

      <xsl:template match="/">

       <xsl:for-each select="/player/album/model/text()[generate-id()
                                   = generate-id(key('model',.)[1])]">
      <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="model"/>
      </li>
      <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="style"/>
      </li>

     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Wanted result:

```
      <MODEL>AA</MODEL>
      <STYLE>BB</STYLE>

      <MODEL>FF</MODEL>
      <STYLE>GG</STYLE>

      <MODEL>HH</MODEL>
      <STYLE>JJ</STYLE>
```

Is it possible to extract these unique value-pairs?

Comment: http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_distinct-values.html

Comment: That is 2.0 xslt

Comment: @KeefRiffhard you should always say whether you need an XSLT 1.0 solution since most XSLT experts are now using 2.0 or 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML (and indeed XSLT) is case-sensitive, so `player` in the xpath in your XSLT will not match `PLAYER` in your XML (and similar for the other nodes).

Additionally, your `xsl:for-each` is selecting text nodes, so doing `<xsl:value-of select="model"/>` is looking for a child node, called `model` of that text node, which obviously doesn't exist.

You could change the expression to `<xsl:value-of select="../../MODEL"/>`, but it might be better to simply change the key to match `ALBUM` nodes instead.

Try this XSLT....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="model" match="/PLAYER/ALBUM" use="MODEL" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/PLAYER/ALBUM[generate-id() = generate-id(key('model',MODEL)[1])]">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="MODEL"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="STYLE"/>
    </li>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not quite sure if you what your exact wanted result is, as the question shows `<MODEL>AA</MODEL><STYLE>BB</STYLE>` as the wanted result, but the XSLT is outputting `LI` tags instead, but it is easy enough to adapt.